# Perform a Stripe transaction without JS to retrieve token

Tags: php, api, curl, stripe-payments

I am trying to perform a stripe transaction without the use of Javascript. Possibly cURL but I cannot figure out the header using the v2 api.

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Card Number</span>
      <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>CVC</span>
      <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc"/>
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <label>
      <span>Expiration (MM/YYYY)</span>
      <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month"/>
    </label>
    <span> / </span>
    <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year"/>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
</form>



<?php
require '../stripe-php/init.php';

//this next line is very wrong
$post = 'client_secret=['sk_07C5ukIdqx'].'&grant_type=authorization_code&code='.$_GET['code'];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $system['stipe']['token_url']);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$decode = json_decode($result);

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("my_secret");
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => 500,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $decode[2], // I am totally guessing the value will be in element #2
   "description" => "Charge for test@example.com"
 ));
?>
```

Most of my issue is getting the token. All of the stripe docs are only using stripe.js and I am not using javascript.

How do I get the stripe token into a PHP variable without the use of Javascript so I can use it for a basic transaction?

Comment: If your server does touch credit card numbers (because you do not use Stripe.js), you'd have to be PCI compliant per PCI SAQ D. This is about 82 pages of documentation that you need to fill out to prove you are compliant. You'd also want to likely hire a QSA which can easily cost thousands of dollars per year.

Comment: Also why are you using Stripe Connect? Stripe connect requires Stripe.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stripe doesn't require your server to be PCI compliant when using `stripe.js`.

If you have a web form to accept credit card data, you want the card token to be created by Stripe. The credit card info is never intended to be sent over the wire to your sever. This is why the form fields in your code have no `name` attribute (name-less fields are not submitted). **This is a good thing.**

If you insist on not using stripe.js, the [API docs on creating a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#create_charge) clearly state

> the source you provide must either be a token, like the ones returned by Stripe.js, or **a associative array containing a user's credit card details**

```
'amount'   => 200, // $2.00,
'currency' => 'usd',
'source'   => [
    'object'    => 'card',
    'number'    => '...'
    'exp_month' => '...',
    'exp_year'  => '...',
    'cvc'       => '...',
]
```

Remove `stripe.js`, put some `name` attributes on your form, and use the `Charge::create()` method without all the preceeding curl stuff.

I have to mention, if I was unclear about the basics of an API that makes credit card processing dead simple, I would be *very* worried about how much I am exposing myself to a potential lawsuit by letting credit card data touch my servers.

Comment: Stripe does requires your site be served over HTTPS

Comment: Thanks. Of course, otherwise the script wouldn't even load!

Comment: No, you can load HTTPS from HTTP (just not vice versa). Stripe requires it for PCI purposes

Comment: @deefour  Wow, whacked with PCI. Your response is 'very' correct. Bare with me while I fish out a working script because it does not exist on the www.

Comment: I don't know JS at all, and I tried the JS script. It was bad dude, it was bad. At best I got NULL for the token

Comment: My brain farts in the comments here aside, I'm happy to help if you update your question to include your JS.

Comment: @deefour  if you slap the code in that link into a file, it will not work. The code in this link  https://bpaste.net/show/1bcd00645548 is from that link and that code does not function.

Comment: I do not know javascript and the best that code will deliver is a NULL value.